# What's the origin of the phrase "fresh off the back"?

Tags: idioms

I often come across this phrase "fresh off the back of something" and although I could never find it in a dictionary, I figured out it means "right after something" but what does it really mean "off the back"? Why is the word "back" used in this phrase?

Comment: "fresh off the back" doesn't seem to be an idiom or a set-phrase at all. It could be a take-off from "fresh off the boat/ block." What is the source?

Comment: I heard it today used by one of the Eurosport commentators. But you can find it in numerous sports articles: http://www.sportzhub.com/news/chances-wide-open-criterium-national-cycling-championships/    http://www.jordanking.co.uk/index.php/news/2013/king-the-fastest-man-in-macau     http://m.fifa.com/confederationscup/news/newsid=2109751/index.html     I googled out about 3.5 million results for "fresh of the back" which is far more than fresh off the block or .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OED has a draft entry from 2010:

> Chiefly *Brit.* ***on (*also *off) the back of*** : on the basis of; by capitalizing on the work or success of.
>
> > 1906   *Baily's Mag.* Jan. 30/2   On the back of every successful form of enterprise kindred ventures are too often floated without much regard to the question of whether they contain the elements of success.
> > ...
> > 1993   *Accountancy* Oct. 49/1   Off the back of its tea business Moran diversified into freight.
> > 2004   H. Kennedy *Just Law* (2005) xiii. 278   The government wins support for the entitlement card on the back of asylum scares.

I suppose it may come from horse-riding, referring either to riding on, or jumping off from, the back of an animal.

[image: Image of acrobats on horseback]

Image c 1875 | [Source](http://www.zazzle.co.uk/vintage_circus_art_post_card-239282360887339512) | Copyright Library of Congress

Comment: This aint fresh at all.

Comment: Seconding @Kris here. The word "fresh" is not in this. If I had to take a guess, I'd say the question comes from a common mixed metaphor (with this phrase and "fresh off the boat" being the mixed sources), or this phrase is a regionalism from somewhere (probably not the US).

Comment: **Fresh[ly]** (adj. and adv.) = direct[ly]; new[ly]; most recent[ly]. 1867   E. A. Freeman Hist. Norman Conquest (1876) I. App. 673   *The narrative..was fresh from the lips of an Englishman.* **fresh off** = **fresh from**

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you’re thinking of the phrase ‘right off the bat’?

i.e. immediately

e.g. Right off the bat we were chatting like old friends.

Comment: While this isn't a bad idea, without supporting research it comes across as more of a comment or opinion than a detailed answer.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].